# Meteor accounts with multiple apps sharing database

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I would like to use google authentication for several meteor apps that are sharing the database. frontend and backoffice app for example.

Could there be any possibility to use `accounts-base` but somehow configure separate users collection for each app?

And also `service-configuration` package uses the same `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration` collection so there seems to be no possibility to store two different google credentials in the same database to use by different `accounts-google` instances. Maybe there is some way how configure collection name?